# Passing wrong model into partial

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I am building my first web app with .net core razor pages.

I am trying to move my menu to be partial, so I can reuse it as I wish but I must be doing something wrong.

The error is:

```
The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'BrambiShop.UI.Pages.IndexModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'BrambiShop.UI.Pages.Shared._SideCategoriesMenuModel'.
```

I know there are few topics on that, but I am struggling " days after work now and I couldnt find any exact solution. I quess I kinda understand what I am doing wrong. But I dont know how to do it right.

I am trying to load the partial from index as follows:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
 @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_SideCategoriesMenu"); }
```

The partial is:

```
    @page
@model BrambiShop.UI.Pages.Shared._SideCategoriesMenuModel
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
@foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
{
    <button class="font-weight-bold" data-toggle="collapse" href="#MenuCollapse_@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => category.Id)"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="MenuCollapse_@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => category.Id)">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => category.Name)
    </button>

    <!-- Collapsible element -->

    <div class="collapse text-center" id="MenuCollapse_@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => category.Id)">
        @foreach (var subCategory in Model.SubCategories.Where(x => x.CategoryId == category.Id))
        {
            <form action="/url/to/action" Method="GET">
                <input type="hidden" name="Property" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => subCategory.Id)" />
                <button type="submit">
                    <i class="fas fa-caret-right pl-1"></i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => subCategory.Name)
                </button>
            </form>
        }
    </div>
    <!-- / Collapsible element -->

}
```

And at last the cshtml.cs

```
using BrambiShop.API.Models;
using BrambiShop.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BrambiShop.UI.Pages.Shared
{
    public class _SideCategoriesMenuModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IApiClient _Client;

        public _SideCategoriesMenuModel(IApiClient client)
        {
            _Client = client;
        }

        public IList<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public IList<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGet()
        {
            Categories = await _Client.GetCategoriesAsync();
            SubCategories = await _Client.GetSubCategoriesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with that please? I did watch about 10 hours of tutorials to build api and the ground of the web, but this damn partial. I just cant find answer to that anywhere.

Thank you very much for any effort.

EDIT
--- index model

```
using BrambiShop.API.Models;
using BrambiShop.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BrambiShop.UI.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {

        public IndexModel()
        {

        }

        public async Task OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Index view has a model of type `IndexModel`. When you put this line

```
 @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_SideCategoriesMenu"); }
```

The same model will be passed to `_SideCategoriesMenu` which is `IndexModel`. This is why you are receiving the exception because the model passed to the `_SideCategoriesMenu` is different since it expects `BrambiShop.UI.Pages.Shared._SideCategoriesMenuModel`.

To go around that, you have to specify the model in the `RenderPartialAsync` method. ex:

```
  @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_SideCategoriesMenu",YOUR_MODEL_HERE); }
```

You can replace YOUR_MODEL_HERE with whatever instance of type `_SideCategoriesMenuModel`. You can have it as a property inside `IndexModel`. ex:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{

    public IndexModel()
    {

    }

    public SideMenuModel SideMenu { get; set;}
    public BrambiShop.UI.Pages.Shared._SideCategoriesMenuModel SideMenuModel{ get; set;}

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
    }
}
}
```

And then use it in your index view

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
 @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_SideCategoriesMenu",Model.SideMenuModel); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The model you use to create the page needs to contain a complete model for the Menu.  Then you need to pass the model in the RenderPartial.

IE:

```
 @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_SideCategoriesMenu", Model.SideMenu); }
```

Edit--

Add the SideMenu property to your Model so you can access it on the page in the above example.

```
using BrambiShop.API.Models;
using BrambiShop.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BrambiShop.UI.Pages
{
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{

    public IndexModel()
    {

    }

    public SideMenuModel SideMenu { get; set;}

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but where should 'Model.SideMenu' come from?

Comment: it would be a property of your "IndexModel".

Comment: I just dont get it, am sorry to ask you for that, never doin it, but I did add the index.cshtml.cs to OP, can you please show me, how do you mean that? I did spend on this problem so many hours, I am desperate.